# Posting images to Basecamp Campfire using API with Python

Tags: python, api, basecamp

I'm new with Python and APIs and I'm trying to upload an image into Basecamp campfire by using Basecamp 3 API. I have achieved authentication with my Basecamp account and was able to post a text message to campfire with this script, but I'm having trouble with images/files, and I couldn't find any examples of how to do this. I posted the image file to '/attachments.json' and gathered its attachable_sgid, but I think I'm not using it correctly.

Here's a link to Basecamp 3 API [documentation](https://github.com/basecamp/bc3-api).

Here's the script that I created:

```
import requests

access_token = 'token here'

account_id = "5437964"
project_id = "29141823"
campfire_id = "5288317671"

base_url = f"https://3.basecampapi.com/{account_id}"

# Post request to acquire attachable_sgid of an image from my filesystem https://github.com/basecamp/bc3-api/blob/master/sections/attachments.md#attachments

attachments_url = f"{base_url}/attachments.json?name=img.png"
img_headers = headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ access_token,
    "Content-Type": "image/png",
    "Content-Length": "123"
    }

with open("img.png", "rb") as img_content:
    image_id = requests.post(attachments_url, headers=img_headers, data=img_content).json()['attachable_sgid']

# Uploading image to Basecamp campfire

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}


img_data = '{"content": "' + image_id + '"}'

campfire_url = f"{base_url}/buckets/{project_id}/chats/{campfire_id}/lines.json"

requests.post(campfire_url, headers=headers, data=img_data)
```

I'm getting the following message `{'status': 400, 'error': 'Bad Request'}`.

Does anyone know how to correctly upload the image in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. First, the image sgid needs to be inside "bc-attachment" html tag like this `<bc-attachment sgid='sgid here'></bc-attachment>`.

Second problem is that at the moment of writing this [Basecamp 3 API does not support posting rich text to campfires](https://github.com/basecamp/bc3-api/blob/master/sections/rich_text.md#rich-text-content-attributes) (even though campfires can have rich text within Basecamp, API is not able to do this), and attachments are considered as rich text.

So instead I have chosen to do this by attaching images to the message board and here is how I did it:

```
import requests

access_token = 'token here'

account_id = "5437964"
project_id = "29141823"
message_board_id = "5288317664"

base_url = f"https://3.basecampapi.com/{account_id}"

# Post request to acquire attachable_sgid of an image from my filesystem https://github.com/basecamp/bc3-api/blob/master/sections/attachments.md#attachments

attachments_url = f"{base_url}/attachments.json?name=img.png"
img_headers = headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ access_token,
    "Content-Type": "image/png",
    "Content-Length": "123"
    }

with open("img.png", "rb") as img_content:
    image_id = requests.post(attachments_url, headers=img_headers, data=img_content).json()['attachable_sgid']

# Uploading image to Basecamp message board

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

data = f"<bc-attachment sgid='{image_id}'></bc-attachment>"

url = f"{base_url}/buckets/{project_id}/message_boards/{message_board_id}/messages.json"

requests.post(url, headers=headers, data='{"subject": "hello", "content": "<div>'+data+'</div>", "status": "active"}')
```

Edit: Adding code snippet for retrieving a new access token due to request in comments.

```
def get_access_token():
    client_id = keys['basecamp_client_id']
    client_secret = keys['basecamp_client_secret']
    redirect_url = keys['basecamp_redirect_uri']
    refresh_token = keys['basecamp_refresh_token']

    refresh_token_url = f"https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/token?type=refresh&refresh_token={refresh_token}&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_url}&client_secret={client_secret}"
    access_token = requests.post(refresh_token_url).json()['access_token']
    return access_token
```

You can further optimize this to only request a new access token once the old one has expired.

Edit 2: I created a python package that simplifies the interaction with Basecamp API - [basecampapi](https://github.com/mare011rs/basecampapi)

Comment: How did you retrieve the fresh access_token ?

Comment: @sspence65 I updated the post with the answer to your question.